# Apply license on data used from answers on Stack Exchange sites

Tags: support, legal, licensing, attribution, creative-commons

I have used some answers from Stack Exchange sites, with desire to republish it. I have prepared some work (something similar to blogpost) from answers of different 3-4 users. How can I properly apply SE license (cc) , how I will attribute all those users, from whom answers the post was created? Do I have to make list of all those users, and also list of links to the answers?

Comment: *Do I have to make list of all those users, and also list of links to the answers?* Yes.